# git using gitlab repo is not allowing me to commit

Tags: git, gitlab

Very strange situation, OS is Linux running in vagrant inside Mac, I have ssh connection to gitlab.

I have branched from master

```
git checkout -b TB-2105_update_mfa
```

I changed some files, do git status

```
On branch TB-2105_update_mfa
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    modified:   src/components/Admin/Users/Details.js
    new file:   src/components/Admin/Users/MultifactorAuthentication.js
```

I do some form of git add, for example

```
git add --all src
```

but also adding the exact path to the two changed components.

I do a commit

```
git commit -m "Some message"
```

I do git status

```
On branch TB-2105_update_mfa
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    modified:   src/components/Admin/Users/Details.js
    new file:   src/components/Admin/Users/MultifactorAuthentication.js
```

What particular sequence of things can cause a commit not to be registered and how do I get out of it.

I checked out master and branched from it with a new name and tried to add, commit etc. but still had the same problem.

I have also tried to commit with --no-verify in case there was some validation I wasn't aware of. None of that is working.

I found a brute force solution which involved saving files elsewhere, deleting repo, moving files back in etc. and then things worked. I figured that was good enough and probably I would not run into this situation again, but less than 24 hours later I have it again!

Noticed that when I do `git diff` this time it is empty, even though the changed files is not. But if I do `git diff --cached` I can see the changes.

Comment: What does `git diff` show you? Are there maybe some post commit hooks active?

Comment: I've actually solved this now by - moving my two files changed out of repo, deleting repo, cloning repo, moving my changes in, branch add commit push. That said the diff showed the files changed as it should, there doesn't seem to be any post commit hooks, so I guess my solution was do in the brute force way, lucky I had just a new file and a couple lines in another file.

Comment: I found that there was a pre-commit hook but I disabled it.